# remote SSH and variable substitution

Tags: bash

The uncommented line complains that 'mus' file doesn't doesn't exist, whereas the commented line behaves as expected and gives me the number of lines in 'mus' file

```
vr=$(ssh $1 "cd $2; count=`cat mus | wc -l`; echo $count")
#vr=$(ssh $1 "cd $2; cat mus | wc -l")
echo $vr
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll be getting this error:

```
cat: mus: No such file or directory
```

Reason is this command

```
count=`cat mus | wc -l`
```

is getting executed locally not on remote host.

To execute multiple commands on remote host use here-doc:

```
ssh -t -t "$1"<<EOF
cd "$2"
c=\$(wc -l < mus)
echo \$c
exit
EOF
```

Answer (score 3):

The uncommented line is looking for file `mus` on your local system, whereas the commented one looks on the remote system. You need to escape the backticks and the `$` in the `count` variable for this to work:

```
vr=$(ssh $1 "cd $2; count=\`cat mus | wc -l\`; echo \$count")
echo $vr
```